# Method of OLEObject not working in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Any ideas why this works (VBA, Excel 2007):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(controlId).ListFillRange = ""
```

but this doesn't:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(controlId).AddItem ("xyz")
```

I don't remember how I solved this before. Right now it says object doesn't support this property or method (it's a combobox).

PS:
This is very strange; I tested an old procedure that worked well as far as I can remember, and now it fails, inexplicably. 
It also contains a reference like this:

```
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").toggleBtn.Caption
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the Object itself to use the AddItem property.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(controlId).Object.AddItem ("xyz")
```